# How to convert separated character by spaces in a div to a normal word in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So if for example I have `<div> H e l l o </div>`, **how can I convert it to `<div>Hello</div>`.**

Being aware that this word could change to even this

`<div> H e l l  o       H     ow    a r e      y        o       U   ?</div>`

Comment: In the second example, do you want "HelloHowareyoU" as a result or " Hello How are yoU" ?

Comment: the first one: "HelloHowareyoU"

Comment: Please modify your question and include what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to first split the content of the element by a `space`(' ') character by Array's `split()`. Then joining the result with no space ('') by Array's `join()`. Try the following:

```js
var text = document.querySelector('div').innerHTML.split(' ').join('');
document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div> H e l l o </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
var div = document.getElementById("foo");
var text = div.innerHTML.split(' ').join('');

div.innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="foo">H e l l o</div>
```

Or, [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
var div = document.getElementById("foo");
var text = div.innerHTML.replace(/ /g, '');

div.innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="foo">H e l l o</div>
```

If you want more than one div, you can implement with:

```js
var divs = document.getElementById('splitJoin').getElementsByTagName("div");

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
   divs[i].innerHTML = divs[i].innerHTML.split(' ').join('');
}
```

```html
<div>H e l l o</div>
<div>F o o</div>
<div>A n o t h e r           O n e</div>
```